# How to Set Scroll View to this XML File?

Tags: android, xml

I'm beginner in android and write this code for my activity XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ExplainImage"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:height="2dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

and show and work good,but i want scroll text view in big text and change text view part to this:

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:height="2dp" />
   </ScrollView>
```

but not show text to me or image,what happen?how can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: you want to scroll both imageview and textview or just textview?

Comment: no i want just scroll in textview

Comment: ok my answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

use this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ExplainImage"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" >
</ImageView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.9">
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="10000dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi, change layout_height attribute of scrollview to wrap_content

Comment: but with your solution,when text big ,image size to show little

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi answer edited! you can set the size of image and text view with layout_weight attribute. notice that you should set weight attribute for scrollview not textview

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi  Did this solve your problem? Or can I help in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview can only have one child view. You are also defining your TextView to have a height of 2dp, if you change it to something like this, your text should display:

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
   </ScrollView>
```

If you need to add multiple views to a Scrollview, you can organise them in a ViewGroup (like you have in your LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

about your question there are some points:

1. ScrollView should only have one child view, in this case: LinearLayout.
2. Android:weight_sum and android:layout_weight usage is for case that you want to fill screen in horizontal or vertical layout. this theory is not good for case that you want to have dynamic TextView to make big and begger with larger Text and more Text inside TextView. in this case you should use wrap_content for android:layout_height to ensure that your TextView height is dynamic and accord to your TextView content.

use this snippet according to your case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ExplainImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"></ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:height="2dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

maybe this help.